# Spreading Object Arguments

Tags: javascript

With the spread syntax, we can expand an array function argument, into distinct parameter variables:

```
var mySpreader = function (nk, mk, zk) {
    console.log('Spread parameter 1: ' + nk);
    for (let v in arguments){
        console.log('Spread parameter: ' + arguments[v]);
    }
};

var spreadArr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
mySpreader(...spreadArr);
```

**Question 1:** Why is it not possible to spread object arguments in the same way? The following throws an error:

```
var spreadObj = {mk: 'm', nk: 'n', zk: 'z'};
mySpreader(...spreadObj);
```

To "fix" the above, it seems we have to use a destructuring assignment to emulate a "spreading":

```
var myDestructor = function ({nk, mk, zk}) {
    console.log('Destructioned parameter: ' + nk);
    for (let v in arguments[0]){
        console.log(v);
        console.log(arguments[0][v]);
    }
};

myDestructor({mk: 'm', nk: 'n', zk: 'z'});
```

**Question 2**: The loop in myDestructor did not work for accessing the destructured variables. Instead, the loop treated the incoming data as a full (non-destructured) object. That was (kind-of) expected. Is there any way to loop through the destructured distinct parameter values?

Comment: You might want to take a look at the object-rest-spread [proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread) which is currently at stage 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is it not possible to spread object arguments in the same way?

Spreading is for iterable stuff, to use an array for *positional* parameters. Objects are not iterable - they don't even have an order!

> The loop in `myDestructor` just treated the incoming data as a full (non-destructured) object. Any idea why?

Well, because the incoming data - the argument that your function was called with - *is* an object. `arguments[0]` is an object. That you have multiple variables initialised from its properties right in the parameter declaration is just syntactic sugar. You could equally have written `function (o) { var {nk, mk, zk} = o;` instead of `function ({nk, mk, zk}) {`.

Comment: Thanks Bergi. The first part is not true though. From MDN: `Spread syntax allows....an object expression to be expanded in places where zero or more key-value pairs (for object literals) are expected`.  Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Comment: Re your answer to my second question, I concluded the same. I was trying to find a way to loop over the distinct destructured variables. Is it not possible? Must I access them individually by name?

Comment: @Magnus MDN is talking about the [object spread draft](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread) there which is not yet official. But still, we're talking about calls here where no key-value pairs are expected.

Comment: @Magnus Yes, one must access variables by name, you cannot loop over them. You can of course loop over the properties of an object, like you did in your code

Comment: The interesting thing here is that spread syntax and destructuring assignments overlap, but covers slightly different tasks. Spread allows us to unpack an array argument into distinct parameter values, but it does not work for an object argument. Destructuring assignments allows us to unpack an object argument into distinct variables, but it does not work for an array argument. Kind of hopeless. I think they need to tidy these use-cases up. Perhaps combine the two into one concise syntax. (I know the two constructs do other things as well, the above is just referring to argument unpacking).

Comment: @Magnus There are two complementary things that use the `...` syntax. You can *spread* a) iterables into calls b) iterables into array literals c) objects into object literals. And you can use *rest syntax* for a) parameters in functions b) arrays in destructuring c) objects in destructuring. But you can never mix objects with arrays (or, more generally, iterables).